# How to forward embedded images in the email body without attachments?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to forward emails with embedded images without the original sender information in Outlook365.

The following VBA code hides the original sender information. However, the embedded images were not shown, only displaying red check boxes.

I don't want to send the images as attachment. Is it possible to forward embedded images in the email body?

```vb
Sub SendTransfer(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
     
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    objMsg.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody
    objMsg.Subject = "xxxx2022" & Item.Subject
    objMsg.Recipients.Add "xxxxxx"
    
    objMsg.Send
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean adding objMsg.Display ?

Comment: Take a look at this [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add). With the ``Position`` parameter you can hide the attachment, setting it to ``zero``.